# How to compile nvptx in Rust

Tags: rust, gpu, nvidia

I have tried to compile nvptx in Rust with the help of [this site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/nvptx/index.html). Here is the code I wrote.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

#[cfg(target_arch="nvptx")]
fn foo() {
    println!("call");
    use std::arch::nvptx::*;
    unsafe {
        let c = malloc(10);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100000));
        free(c);
    }
}


fn main() {
    #[cfg(target_arch="nvptx")]
    foo();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I've done my research.
I thought it might be possible to compile to nvptx by doing `cargo run --target nvptx64-nvidia-cuda`. However, when I tried to run it, I received the following error.

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`.
  |.
  = note: the `nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `core_nvptx`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

So, I set rust to nightly and added a target for nvptx.
`rustup target add nvptx64-nvidia-cuda`.
So we added
`cargo run --target nvptx64-nvidia-cuda`.
I received the same error as above when I did

## postscript

I have created a separate nvptx crate with the following file structure.

```
├─ Cargo.lock
├─ Cargo.toml
├─ nvptx
│ ├─ Cargo.lock
│ ├─ Cargo.toml
└─ src
└─ lib.rs
r└─ src
    r└─ main.rs
```

I created a `.cargo/config` file in the nvptx crate.
In it, I wrote the following

```
[build].
target = "nvptx64-nvidia-cuda".
```

And here is how the contents of `nvptx/src/lib.rs` looks

```rust
#! [feature(stdsimd)]
#! [no_std] #!

use core::arch::nvptx;
use core::ffi::c_void;

unsafe fn cuda_alloc(size: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    nvptx::malloc(size)
}

unsafe fn cuda_free(ptr: *mut c_void) {
    nvptx::free(ptr);
}
```

Also, the code in `src/main.rs` is as follows.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread::sleep;

use nvptx::*;

fn foo() {

    println!("call");
    unsafe {
        let ptr = cuda_alloc(10 as usize);
        cuda_free(ptr);
    }
    
}


fn main() {
    foo();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

When I compiled this, I received the following error.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `core::arch::nvptx`
 --> nvptx/src/lib.rs:4:5
  | use core::arch::nvptx
4 | use core::arch::nvptx;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `nvptx` in `arch`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `nvptx`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Rust version:
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.54.0-nightly (f94942d84 2021-05-19)

Comment: if `rustup target add nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` succeeded I don't believe you. check again

Comment: @Stargateur I actually did.And I have updated the current status.